# I am looking for a software that can give me a set of discrete points from a picture of a graph

Tags: linux, open-source, web

The graph in particular is Electrocardiographs(ECGs), on which I need to do further analysis. The analysis cannot be done on a photograph, hence I need the software that outputs a sequence of graphical points.

The software is preferable in linux and/or web. [image]

EDIT: I need a software that can configured to do the data extraction automatically.

Comment: Just do a google search on “digitize data from graph image”. Several options to try.